# Instance Variables in a Partial for Sign-Ups

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a website that will require users to sign-up, in order to perform various tasks. However, I am having some trouble with sign-ups.

I have a partial named **_form.html.erb**, which is rendered in **application.html.erb** (so that it appears on every page users navigate to) as a fade-in, fade-out modal form (I am using Twitter Bootstrap). What do I need to do, in order to pass an instance variable to this partial and have a user created in the database, once the user presses the submit button? Do I need to create a new method in application_controller.rb and a new user model?

Thank you for the help!

*Note:* I've read this link (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), but did not get much out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assign a local variable when rendering the partial that stores the user object.

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= render "users/form", :user => User.new %>
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render "form", :user => @user %>
```

Using this technique your form would reference the local variable.

```
<%= form_for user do |f| %>
  <!-- form fields here -->
<% end %>
```